# Instalar Electron sin conexión a internet

Tags: npm, electron

Necesito instalar Electron, pero mi conexión es muy limitada, ademas de estar bajo un proxy.

Por políticas de seguridad, el comando `npm install electron-prebuilt` no me funciona. Sin embargo, puedo acceder a un repo local de módulos para Node.js.

Configuré `npm` para que descargue los módulos desde ese repo local. Esto funciona con cualquier módulo, pero con `electron-prebuilt` no.

Al ejecutar `npm install electron-prebuilt` en la consola, me dice que está descargando desde GitHub el .zip `electron-v1.1.0-win32-x64.zip`, acción que no va a poder cumplir por todas las limitaciones de mi conexión.

Yo descargué ese fichero manualmente, pero no se donde ubicarlo. ¿Alguna idea de donde está intentando buscar el fichero la instalación de Electron?

Answer (score 1):

No creo que puedas *engañar* a `npm` para que use tu fichero local, pero en principio, con el `electron-vX.X.X-YYY.zip` que te has bajado desde las [releases](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases) del repo oficial de GitHub **ya tienes todo lo necesario**.

Descomprime el archivo, y encontrarás un binario llamado `electron` (`electron.exe` en tu caso, si estás en Windows).

Como el `.zip` contiene todas las dependencias, con eso debería bastar. Guarda todo lo que has descomprimido en un directorio que te resulte cómodo, y para ejecutar tus aplicaciones usa:

```
ruta_de_electron\electron.exe app.js
```

*(Sustituye `app.js` por el nombre/ruta del archivo con tu código)*

Para que te hagas una idea, ese binario **funciona igual que cuando te lo instalas con `npm`**, así que no deberías tener ningún problema.